# Fail to upload multiple files

Tags: node.js, express, multer, form-data

I try to upload multiple files using multer.
here is the frontend code:

```
const onFileUpload = () => {
    // Create an object of formData
    const formData = new FormData();

    // Update the formData object
    formData.append(
        "myFiles",
        selectedFiles,
    );

    // Details of the uploaded file
    console.log(selectedFiles);

    // Request made to the backend api
    // Send formData object
    axios.post("api/uploadfile", formData);
  }
```

here is the backend code:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({});

const uploadFile = async (req, res) => {

    console.log("uploadFile: ",req.files)
return res.status(200).send("alive");

};

router.post(
    '/uploadfile',
    multer({storage}).array('myFiles'),
    uploadFile,
);
```

the problame is when i consol.log `req.files` i resive empty array but i should recive the files array.
what i'm doing wrong

Comment: Does it work if you send the request through e.g. postman or curl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using this with the wrong way.

Change it to:

```
const onFileUpload = () => {
  // Create an object of formData
  const formData = new FormData();

  for (const key of Object.keys(selectedFiles)) {
    formData.append("myFiles", selectedFiles[key])
  }

  // Details of the uploaded file
  console.log(selectedFiles);

  // Request made to the backend api
  // Send formData object
  axios.post("api/uploadfile", formData);
}
```